# VBA Delete Sharepoint File - Recycle Bin

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

Is there a way to delete a file from SharePoint using VBA without calling the SharePoint API and still have it go to the recycle bin? The "Kill" statement removes the files but does not send them to the SharePoint recycle bin, so I am hesitant to use it in a macro that others will run.

Comment: http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2008/08/vba-send-file-to-recycle-bin.html

Comment: @brax Thanks, that seems to work on locally stored files, but not on sharepoint