# How to delete a excel file in Sharepoint Online using VBA

Tags: vba, sharepoint-online

As per title, I am trying to write code that deletes an excel file from a sharepoint online folder, using only vba.

Since I am very new to VBA, I have no idea where to begin with

Answer (score 1):

Something as the following code should work.

Please note that the [`Kill` function](https://analystcave.com/vba-reference-functions/vba-file-functions/vba-kill-function/) does [not move the file to the trash bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46451726/vba-delete-sharepoint-file-recycle-bin). Use with care!

```
Sub RemoveSharePointFile()

Dim folder As String, file As String, fulladdress As String

folder = "https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/test/"
file = "test.xls" 'must include extension

fulladdress = folder & file
Kill fulladdress 

MsgBox "File '" & file & "' was successfully deleted.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Tim.

I will try this for sure.

"Please note that the Kill function does not move the file to the trash bin."
What are the implications of this?

Comment: It would mean irretrievable files, most likely

Comment: Hi Tim, I tried what you suggested but without any luck.

I used the code you provided but I get "error 53: file not found", despite the fact the file is there.

I am pretty sure the path is correct, since I copy and pasted the adress used to create the file in the first place.

Comment: Yes this method does not work with sharepoint links to files

Answer (score 0):

on cmd create a local folder point to sharepoint with "net use" (net use x:\collaborate.yousite.com@SSL\sites...) then

delete the file from the local driver

kill x:\yourfile.pfd